# Probability of minimal distance being less than d

Tags: probability

Consider a disk of radius $R$. We drop $N$ points onto its surface in a random way so that the points are uniformly distributed on the disk and the corresponding events sre independent.
What is the probability that the minimal distance measured from the disk centre is less than $d$?

My attempt:

The probabililty that a points distance from the centre is less than $d$
is $\frac{d^{2}}{R^{2}}$.

The probabililty that a points distance from the centre is greater than
or equal to $d$ is $\frac{R^{2} - d^{2}}{R^{2}}$.

A special case is when all the points share $d$ as the common distance
from the centre: $\frac{d^{2N}}{R^{2N}}$

Another special case is when a single points radius is $d$ and $N-1$
points are located in the outer ring: $\frac{d^{2}}{R^{2}}\frac{(R^{2} - d^{2})^{N-1}}{R^{2N-2}}$

Questions: How shall I proceed from this point?
Is my reasoning correct?

Edit:

The complement of the probability that all distances are greater than $d$ is
the following:

$1 - \frac{(R^{2} - d^{2})^{N}}{R^{2N}}$.

So this is the probability that the minimal distance is less than or equal to $d$.

Comment: When you say you drop the points at random, do you mean they are i.i.d and each is uniformly distributed on the disk?

Comment: Note that the probability that a point is exactly distance $d$ from the center is $0$.  So your two "special" cases should both have probability $0$.

Comment: I've just edited the post.

Comment: You have found "the probability that a point's distance from the centre is greater than or equal to $d$" so now find the probability that all the points' distances from the centre are greater than or equal to $d$, and then the probability that any of the points' distances from the centre is less than $d$

Comment: "all distances greater than $d$" = "minimal distance greater than $d$" = complement of "minimal distance less than or equal to $d$"